# How can I grab the current selection of a ComboBox as a String

Tags: c#, wpf

So, I'm trying to get the selected value of a ComboBox, and if it equals a certain value the loop below should run. However, "We Hit Here1" always hits, but "We Hit Here2" never hits. How am I able to get this to run? I've tried a few other solutions I've found online, but none have resolved the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
private void HourSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Object curSelection = hourSearchReq.SelectedValue.ToString();
            //curSelection = curSelection.Trim();
            currentStudentName = hourSeachStudent.Text;
            Console.WriteLine("We Hit Here1");
            if (curSelection.Equals("Full Name"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We Hit Here2");
                foreach (String x in nameUser)
                {

                    if (x.Contains(currentStudentName))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("We Hit Here3");
                        currentStudentUser = x.Substring(x.IndexOf(",") + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                currentStudentUser = hourSeachStudent.Text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: There's a subtle difference between `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` (that mostly depends on your XAML). I'd try using `SelectedItem`. Also the standard disclaimer about not writing WPF this way (and using MVVM instead) definitely applies here.

Comment: You typically don't directly use ComboBoxItem at all. If you add item strings either by `hourSearchReq.Items.Add("Full Name")` or `hourSearchReq.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Full Name", ... }`, the SelectedItem property directly returns the selected item as a string, and you can simply cast it like `string currentStudentName = (string)hourSearchReq.SelectedItem;`. You should not use the `Text` property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hourSearchReq.SelectedValue default return `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem`

[image]

if you use only strings in ComboBox then use the ComboBox.Text property

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var curSelection = cmbTest.Text;
            Console.WriteLine("We Hit Here1");
            if (curSelection.Equals("Item2"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We Hit Here2");               
            }
        }
```

P.S. But I would advise you to use the MVVM approach

Comment: It's only strings, and I think for my purpose this solution would be perfect. Thank you so much for the help!